# How to use loop on static page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, loops

I want to loop posts form different category on static page. So , I have 5 static pages , and 5 different categories. I want to loop posts from one category per one page.

The way I do it is this:

```
> $novo = new WP_Query('cat=3'); // 3 is category id I want display
> while($novo->have_posts()) : $novo->the_post(); 
> 
> <!-- post model -->
> 
> endwhile;
```

The problem with this that I don't know how to display pagination in static pages with many posts in single category.

What's the best way to make loop on static pages with easy navigation implementation? 
what you usually use to make loop on static page?

Any help is appreciated :D

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking. Are you trying to display all the posts for a particular category? There's a link in Wordpress that automatically does this, usually site.com/c/catname.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the question is wrong. An static page is one that DOES NOT HAVE QUERIES or receive any kind of information from other sources.

If you want to paginate a single post wich has more than one page, you should use:

```
<?php wp_link_pages('before=<p>&after=</p>&next_or_number=number&pagelink=page %'); ?>
```

If you want to paginate a page wich have `N` posts:

```
wp_pagenavi():
```